# Notation for near optimal solution

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, optimization, notation

Usually, $x^*$ is used to denote the optimal solution to a maximization problem.

I need a notation to describe a solution that is not optimal but "good enough."  In my case this solution is the first $x$ to get into a vicinity of the optimal.

Is there a standard notation to denote a "good enough" solution?  I have considered $x^{**}$, $x^{+}$, $x^{GE}$), but am not very convinced that these are standard.  What do you you think would be the best notation?

Many thanks!

Comment: $x^{:(} {}{}{}{}$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE, thanks for your question. Hope you stay around and contribute to the site. I haven't seen a standard notation for such things.

Comment: @MPW hilarious :)

Comment: Maybe $\widetilde{x}$? That is generally used as approximation to something. In your case this something is the optimal solution. (`\widetilde{x}`)